# Mobx observable only get updated if i log it

Tags: react-native, logging, mobx

I have a hook that uses an observable which is a map - `peripheralStore.connectedDevices`. this map consists with values which are also observables - `Sensor`

The hook updates when `peripheralStore.connectedDevices` changes, but the values themself aren’t.

**Funny thing about it is that once i log the entire map, the hook get re-renders with every changes in the the map's values**

My Custom Hook:

```
export default function useSensor(): UseSensorObj {
  const { peripheralStore } = useStore()
  const devices = peripheralStore.connectedDevices
  const isConnected: boolean = !_.isEmpty(devices)

  const value = devices?.values().next()
  //console.log(`log: ${JSON.stringify(devices)}`)
  const batteryLevel = value?.value?.battery

  return { devices, batteryLevel, isConnected }
}
```

here is how i updated the map:

```
 class PeripheralStore implements IPeripheralStore {

   constructor(...) {
     makeAutoObservable(this, {}, { autoBind: true })
     ...
   }

   private async initSensor(sensor: ISensor) {
     await runInAction(async () => {
       sensor.init()
       this.connectedDevices.set(sensor.peripheral.id, sensor)
     })
   }
 ...
}
```

and here is how i update the object's data:

```
 class Sensor implements ISensor {
   constructor(...) {
     makeAutoObservable(this, {}, { autoBind: true })
     ...
   }
   this.monitorCharacteristic(...) => {
    runInAction(() => {
      const battery = decodeByteArrival[17]

      if (this.battery !== battery) {
        this.battery = battery
      }
    ...
    })
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to reread this chapter of the docs https://mobx.js.org/understanding-reactivity.html#understanding-reactivity

> MobX reacts to any existing observable property that is read during the execution of a tracked function.
>
> "reading" is dereferencing an object's property, which can be done through "dotting into" it (eg. user.name) or using the bracket notation (eg. user['name'], todos[3]) or destructuring (eg. const {name} = user).

When you do `JSON.stringify` it basically reads every property of your object/array or whatever, so this hook will rerender on any property change. And when you don't have `JSON.stringify` you only read top level property (array/object itself) so the hook only reacts to that property change, not inner ones.

Comment: Interesting, but i am accessing (reading) the observable property in "const batteryLevel = value?.value?.battery"

Comment: Then you are probably reading wrong value (not the one that changed)? Could you make minimal reproduction on https://codesandbox.io/?

Comment: will try, not trivial since the events come form BLE